# How can I transfer phone number of one database to another database related to each other in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The user have various roles ie. admin, executive and traniee. When I signup as a admin the data username, email, phone .... will be saved on table admin as well as user table. At first I have not pass params phone to user. So, it takes nil data at User table. Now I want to pass data phone from admin to user.

This is user model:

```
  has_many :user_roles, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :roles, through: :user_roles

  has_one :trainee, dependent: :destroy
  has_one :admin, dependent: :destroy
```

This is admin model:

```
belongs_to :user
```

This is admin controller:

```
 def create
  email        = params[:admin][:email]
  role         = Role.find_by_name('admin')

    if email.split('@').first.include?(params[:admin][:office_kind])
      username = "Ad_#{email.split('@').first}"
    else
      username = "Ad_#{params[:cd_admin][:office_kind]}_#{email.split('@').first}"
    end

    user = User.create(email: email, password: '227127', role_ids: role.id, username: username)

    @admin = user.build_admin(admin_params.merge(creator_id: current_user.id, registered_date: Date.today,
                                                          username:   username))
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: why do you save a user twice, once in table user and once in table admin/executive/trainee? This doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @Nicole The user have different roles. User login from their assign roles. So, when user login roles.id, email, username is passed to them. Admin, Executive, Trainee all are the user with different roles.That's why

Comment: Is there a reason not to have a User table with columns for role (e.g. booleans for admin, trainee etc.)? It would be simpler and it sounds like the role is an attribute of the record that may change over time (someone starts as a trainee and then graduates from that) without needing to create an entirely new user record for them.

Comment: It doesn't make sense that when someone logs in as an admin, their information gets stored in the table `user` and in the table `admin`. Having only the table `user` with a column called `role` should be enough.

Comment: @Nicole you are right. This project is not started by me. I just involved in this project to get my hand dirty. To start from beginning is messy for me.